SUMIFS with Arrayformula in Google Sheets from multiple array
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvZerzOiW0vdewnfZT47WuU3TPlW15UHUSpvII1HE50/edit#gid=0
I want to use an arrayformula array function with one formula in cell N4 to get the q'ty values in that table with SUMIFS.
i did like this
=ArrayFormula(sumifs($E$4:$E$29,$B$4:$B$29,N3:S3,$D$4:$D$29,M4:M20,$C$4:$C$29,L4:L20)) 
But I think I got the wrong answer.

I recommend using QUERY as suggested by @doubleunary, but if you want to do this with SUMIFS you can use the MAP function:
=MAP(N3:S3,LAMBDA(m,MAP(L4:L20,M4:M20,LAMBDA(s,i,SUMIFS(E4:E,B4:B,m,C4:C,s,D4:D,i)))))

Or you can use SUMIF with concatenated criteria and criteria range:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(B4:B&C4:C&D4:D,N3:S3&L4:L20&M4:M20,E4:E))

EDIT: Solution with MAKEARRAY
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(L4:M20),COLUMNS(N3:S3),LAMBDA(r,c,SUMIFS(E4:E,B4:B,INDEX(N3:S3,,c),C4:C,INDEX(L4:L20,r),D4:D,INDEX(M4:M20,r))))


wow it's really amazing thing i've never thought of ..   Thanks alot !

do you happen to know the solution with 'makearray' function ? @z..

Hi, I have one more question. I tried with sum, makearray as follows but it turned out to be incorrect.
How should I fix it?
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(H4:H20),COLUMNS(I3:N3),LAMBDA(r,c,
let(
sum,
sum(
(B4:B29=index(I3:N3,c))*
(C4:C29=index(G4:G20,r))*
(D4:D29=index(H4:H20,r))*
(E4:E29)),
sum)
))

Use query(), like this:
=query( 
  A3:E, 
  "select Col3, Col4, sum(Col5) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col3, Col4 
   pivot Col2", 
  1 
)

The formula will show blanks where there is no data. To fill in zeros instead of blanks, use this:
=let( 
  table, query( 
    A3:E, 
    "select Col3, Col4, sum(Col5) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col3, Col4 
     pivot Col2", 
    1 
  ), 
  arrayformula(if(table = "", 0, table)) 
)

See query() and let().

Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but wiki sites that use the Q&A format. See Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. To ask "how do I do this with sumifs()" you would have to justify that requirement with something other than "i wanna".
